# Android port forwarding

Tags: java, android, sockets, router

How can I make a port forwarding from a android device to router using the IP from another device?

I want to connect from android device externally to a routers public ip:port so that I can access the hardware device that is connected to the router.(Android -> external IP:Port) -> Router -> hardware Device(hardware device has its own IP and mac).

[image]

Code:

```
    PortMapping mapping = new PortMapping();
    UnsignedIntegerTwoBytes externalPort = new UnsignedIntegerTwoBytes(22555L);
    UnsignedIntegerTwoBytes internalPort = new UnsignedIntegerTwoBytes(80L);

    mapping.setDescription("HardwareDescription");
    mapping.setEnabled(true);
    mapping.setExternalPort(externalPort);
    mapping.setInternalClient("192.168.2.68");
    mapping.setInternalPort(internalPort);
    mapping.setProtocol(PortMapping.Protocol.TCP);
    mapping.setRemoteHost("192.168.2.254");


    mUpnpService = new MyUpnpServiceImpl(new PortMappingListener(mapping));
    mUpnpService.getRouter();
    mUpnpService.getControlPoint().search(SCAN_TIMEOUT);
```

UpnpServiceImpl:

```
private class MyUpnpServiceImpl extends UpnpServiceImpl {

    public MyUpnpServiceImpl(RegistryListener... listeners) {
        super(new AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration(getWifiManager()),
                listeners);
    }

    @Override
    public Router getRouter() {
        return super.getRouter();
    }
    @Override
    protected Router createRouter(ProtocolFactory protocolFactory,
            Registry registry) {
        return new AndroidWifiSwitchableRouter(configuration,
                protocolFactory, getWifiManager(), getConnectivityManager());
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't crash, but also it doesn't create any port!

Is this possible? 
If the answer is yes, can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: If you want to award points you need to set a bounty on this question.

Comment: Also it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you wanting to access the android device externally via the gateway?

Comment: First comment: Unfortunately this question eligible for bounty in 2 days :(

Second comment: I want to connect from android device externally to a routers public ip:port so that I can access the gateway device that is connected to the router.(Android -> external IP:Port) -> Router -> Gateway Device(gateway device has its own IP and mac).

Comment: If you're accessing externally aren't you going via the gateway already (as its name implies)? I think it isn't an Android programming issue anyway but more a configuration issue of your hardware.

Comment: Not quite...I have a box(hardware equipment) it has an IP:port and it's connected to my router. I want to connect to this device from home to another location. My Router has the external IP 86.XX.XX.XX and the hardware device has also an IP 192.168.X.XX.
I want to connect to 86.XX.XX.XX:8123 -> this port is bound to the IP of the hardware device that I have.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly ... your android is outside of your network and you want to connect to the gateway that is behind a router ... then you can't do the upnp forwarding from the android device. This has to come from inside of the network, not from the outside.

Comment: 1/2 correct - I want to do a port forwarding from the android device while I'm connected to the same network as the as the hardware device - and after I've done the port forwarding ...connect to another network or 3G and access the hardware device.

Comment: Let's see if I got it. You have a router and an equipment which is connected to the router and it has an open IP/Port, you want to access that equipment from an Android device thru your public router IP. If this is the case all you have to do is a NAT in your router, configure the router so that anybody from outside (internet) which connects to that port the router will automatically forward the request to that IP/Port.

Comment: Yes is correct...do you know any solution for this issue I have? If yes you sir are my hero :)

Comment: That would be a **router configuration** question, not a software development question, and so off topic here.  If you figure out a process for configuring the router using a remote management API, then difficulties with implementing that in an Android app could be an on-topic question.  But how to configure the router itself is off topic.

Comment: I want to configure (port open) the router from my application that runs on Android device...

Comment: First you need to find out how the router of interest **can be configured** by remote device of any sort, and that is **a question which is off-topic here**.  Once you know how the router can be configured, **specific problems with implementing that on Android** could be on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer for this question.
The first step is to enable the **UPNP** option on router, after this step import the library net.sbbi.upnp search for the router (IGD) device and use the method **addPortMapping**.

Here is an example for anyone that want to open o port on router using any IP, not just from the current device that the app runs.

https://github.com/ManolescuSebastian/Port_Forward_Android

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to your router via a desktop with any explorer (iexplorer, chrome, etc) try to connect to address `192.168.1.1` (the one that is your `gateway`, execute `ipconfig` from a `cmd` window and you'll see a line which says what is your `gateway` [the router]), type in the router's user and password and configure it. Depends on the router and model, consult the router's manual. Look for something that says `NAT`, `Port Forward` or `Virtual Server`. You can open a single port or a range of ports, type in the IP address where those ports should be forwarded, in this case the IP of your equipment.  If any doubt, search the internet for your router's name and how to open/forward ports.

Good luck.