# I would like to setup an android phone to port forward incoming VNC connection to a tethered VNC server enabled touchscreen

Tags: android, portforwarding, vnc

I would like to achieve the following setup:

ME AT OFFICE WITH VNC VIEWER--->INTERNET--->ANDROID PHONE --->VNC SERVER ON MAPLE SYSTEMS TOUCHSCREEN IN FIELD

I can pretty much figure out everything except how to port forward 5900 through the phone.  Any help or constructive criticism would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I cant tell if this is real, but it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399994/android-port-forwarding , so if it is, there's your answer

Comment: Ya, it's kinda the same.  I will pursue that route.  Thanks.